# how to get the layers of a docker image on local host

Tags: docker

Just started playing with docker on Ubuntu. I pulled a docker image as follows.

```
docker pull coreos/apache
```

Now I see there there three layers being pulled.

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from coreos/apache
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
5e160ca0bb5a: Pull complete 
1f92e2761bfd: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9af520cee7bedcda564970ff790cdf2e72b6daccce8539f6b3c880ed7fc21091
Status: Downloaded newer image for coreos/apache:latest
```

From the above, I see that there are three layers for this image.

But now, lets say I close and reopen the terminal, how can I get the layers(same info above) of this image. What is the command?

When I do docker images I get this.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID           CREATED             SIZE
centos              latest              0584b3d2cf6d        9 days ago          196.5 MB
hello-world         latest              c54a2cc56cbb        4 months ago        1.848 kB
coreos/apache       latest              5a3024d885c8        2 years ago         294.4 MB
```

Now that I know the image id, how can I get the layers for that image id.
The *tree* option as in

```
docker images --tree
```

is not working anymore. It seems to be removed. If not one command how can I get that using a sequence of command at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now that the image has been downloaded to your local host (in layers), even if you kill your terminal and log back in, the image will still exist on your host. it's downloaded in layers, but resides as an image on your localhost that you can now instantiate into a container using 'docker run'

if you want to pull the image down again and see all the layers being pulled, you can first erase your image (docker rmi ), then do your 'docker pull coreos/apache' again. HTH

edit: to show actual layers that went into an image, run:

```
docker history <imageid>
```

Comment: I understand that, but what I want is to know the layers an image comprises of. How do I get that info?

Comment: @VivekDev for that, you can use 'docker history <image>', as outlined here:

Comment: Better than history, docker inspect coreos/apache seems to be giving better info.

Comment: @VivekDev absolutely, 'docker inspect' provides a *lot* of detail, but it's not as easy to read for someone new to Docker, like you said you were. nor does it seem to show the sizes for each layer, like 'docker history' does. using both certainly provides a lot of insight into what's going on though. enjoy docker -- such useful technology!

Comment: @melgart, just added how to extract the info from result of `docker inspect`

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `busybox`, here is how I would get it.

`docker inspect busybox` - would show long configuration in `json` format and below is the excerpt from it to get the layers.

```
"RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:e88b3f82283bc59d5e0df427c824e9f95557e661fcb0ea15fb0fb6f97760f9d9"
            ]
        }
```

You can simple filter it by below command using `--format` option of `docker inspect` which would give exactly what OP is looking for.

```
rao @ ubuntu $ docker inspect --format '{{.RootFS.Layers}}' busybox
[sha256:e88b3f82283bc59d5e0df427c824e9f95557e661fcb0ea15fb0fb6f97760f9d9]
```